# Skimage: how to show image

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am novice at skimage and I try to show the image in my ipython notebook:\

```
from skimage import data, io
coins = data.coins()
io.imshow(coins)
```

But I see only the following string:

```
<matplotlib.image.AxesImage at 0x7f8c9c0cc6d8>
```

Can anyboby explain how to show image right under the code like here:
[Correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvE9y.png)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Just add `matplotlib.pyplot.show()` after the `io.imshow(coins)` line.

```
from skimage import data, io
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


coins = data.coins()
io.imshow(coins)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, but maybe it works for OP.

Comment: @this-vidor strange enough. Try running that in a python console.

Comment: Where do you think I was running it!

Comment: @this-vidor can you show me your output? I guess your matplotlib backend is not configured properly.

Comment: Run '%matplotlib inline' somewhere in your Notebook first, then it should show it inline

Comment: There is no output besides what OP indicated. `plt.show()` doesn't raise or anything, it just doesn't show anything. Glad it worked for OP. This is not actually an issue I need to resolve.

Comment: @Tehada sorry, I missed the ipython notebook part. As Jan van der Vegt says, just put the `%matplotlib inline` magic command to inline the images inside your notebook.

Comment: For this to work for me, I had to also  do `io.use_plugin('matplotlib')`

Answer (score 10):

images using skikit-image,matplotlib,SciPy,NumPy  library

```
import os
# importing io from skimage 
import skimage
from skimage import io
# way to load image from file
file = os.path.join(skimage.data_dir, 'E:/img.jpg') 
myimg = io.imread(file) 
# way to show the input image 
io.imshow(myimg) 
io.show()
```

Answer (score 9):

To display pending images, you need `io.show()` following `io.imshow(coins)`

Comment: The problem with this answer that it duplicates previous

Answer (score 4):

You can use skimage and matplotlib.pyplot as follows

```
from skimage import io, data  
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# get coin image
coin = data.coins()    

# display image   
plt.imshow(coin)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow()` instead of `io.imshow(coins)`.

```py
from skimage import data.0
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

coins = data.coins()
plt.imshow(coins)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import skimage
from skimage import io

img = io.imread('img.jpg')
io.imshow(img)
io.show()
```

Comment: I show the image in VSC

Answer (score 0):

It probably occurs because you didn't declare matplotlib inline instruction
please try the following code instructions, they will be helpful:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
plt.imshow(img)
```